# How to use actionperformed in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm reworking my code here and I get the following errors:

```
ActionPerformed cannot be resolved to a type
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (fenetre)
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (fenetre)

at fenetre.<init>(fenetre.java:12)
at Test.main(Test.java:4)
```

code

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class fenetre extends JFrame implements ActionPerformed{
    JPanel pan=new JPanel (new FlowLayout());                   //  instancier un  objet jpanel qui contiendra nos composents 
    private JButton nouveau_utilisateur ;
    private JButton identification;

    // le constructeur 
    public fenetre (){

        setTitle("la reconnaissance de la siganteur manuscrite ");        // la taille de la fenetre 
        setSize(400,500);                                                   //positionné notre fenetre au centre 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);                                    //terminer le processus lorsque on clique sur la croix rouge 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        nouveau_utilisateur=new JButton("nouveau_utilisateur");
        identification =new JButton("identification");
        identification.addActionListener(this);
        nouveau_utilisateur.addActionListener(this);


        pan.add(identification);
        pan.add(nouveau_utilisateur);

        add(pan);   

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you read about the difference between interfaces (such as ActionListener) and methods (such as actionPerformed()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class that is being added as an action listener must implement the `ActionListener` interface. So `fenetre` in your case.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class fenetre extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JPanel pan=new JPanel (new FlowLayout());                   //  instancier un  objet jpanel qui contiendra nos composents 
    private JButton nouveau_utilisateur ;
    private JButton identification;

    // le constructeur 
    public fenetre (){

        setTitle("la reconnaissance de la siganteur manuscrite ");        // la taille de la fenetre 
        setSize(400,500);                                                   //positionné notre fenetre au centre 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);                                    //terminer le processus lorsque on clique sur la croix rouge 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        nouveau_utilisateur=new JButton("nouveau_utilisateur");
        identification =new JButton("identification");
        identification.addActionListener(this);
        nouveau_utilisateur.addActionListener(this);

        pan.add(identification);
        pan.add(nouveau_utilisateur);

        add(pan);   

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Some code
    }

}
```

Comment: Edited to make it contain your entire code block. You need to change `implements ActionPerformed` to `implements ActionListener` and you need to add a method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`